# JS Function returning Function instead of value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to make a simple mathematical function using JS by fetching data from Firebase Database.
We have two types- Income and Expenditure.

Initially here is the code snippet for referencing to Firebase

```
    let reference = firebase.database().ref("expenditure");
    let reference1=firebase.database().ref("income");
```

This lets us create two different Databases with names **expenditure** and **income**

Now, I have created two functions to loop through the elements in Database and add it to a variable

## These functions should return expenditure and income respectively.

```
var income=0;

var expenditure=0;



function amount(data){
    let expens = data.val();
    let keys = Object.keys(expens);
    console.log(keys.length);

    for( let i=0;i<keys.length;i++){

    let a =keys[i];
    let amount_a = expens[a].Amount;

    var p=parseInt(amount_a);
    var expenditure=p+expenditure;

    }


    return expenditure;
}



function amount1(data){
    let expens = data.val();
    let keys = Object.keys(expens);
    console.log(keys.length);

    for( let i=0;i<keys.length;i++){

    let a =keys[i];
    let amount_a = expens[a].Amount;

    var p=parseInt(amount_a);
    var income=p+income;

    }


    return income;
}
```

As you can see I have declared two functions to return income and expenditure

Now, I have called these in another function called `result()`

```
function result(){
    var a=reference.on("value",amount);
    var b=reference1.on("value",amount1);
    console.log(b-a);
}

result();
```

This should return me Net Amount(Income-expenditure)
But, I am getting the same functions for `amount(data),amount1(data)` in console.log instead of returning the value of income and expenditure.

I have tried several ways but couldn't figure this out.

[Checkout the Console.log here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzsei.png)

[console.log({a,b})](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYseU.png)

Comment: Are you sure `reference.on("value",amount)` returns a number? and also can you print console something like this `console.log({ a, b })`

Comment: It should call amount() function I guess. Otherwise how can I call amount() function?

Comment: Image added to post at last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase `.on(...)` function does not return the value from the database, it sends the value to the callback function passed as a parameter.

You should update the variables with the callback functions. Assuming your database structure is like this:

```
(root)
-- expenditure
---- (key)
------- Amount: 0
---- (key)
------- Amount: 0
-- income
---- (key)
------- Amount: 0
---- (key)
------- Amount: 0
```

Then your code should be more of something like this:

```
let expenditureRef = firebase.database().ref("expenditure");
let incomeRef = firebase.database().ref("income");

let expenditures = 0;
let income = 0;

let netAmount = 0;


expenditureRef.on("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        expenditures += parseInt(childSnapshot.val().Amount);
        netAmount = income - expenditures;
    }
});

incomeRef.on("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        income += parseInt(childSnapshot.val().Amount);
        netAmount = income - expenditures;
    }
});
```

I wasn't able to test this out, so if this doesn't work, feel free to tell me and I can try to fix it.

I also strongly recommend reading through the documentation here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

As the `reference.on()` returns the callback you just simply need to modify the code like this

```
function result(){
    var a=reference.on("value",amount)();
    var b=reference1.on("value",amount1)();
    console.log(b-a);
}
```

This will return you desired value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is going to fix your problem, but you should remove the re-declaration of expendature

```
for(...){
    ...
    var expenditure=p+expenditure;
}
return expenditure;
```

The expenditure that you are defining inside of that for loop only exists for that for loop and should not be available outside of it; it's reference should override the global level expenditure variable.

I would suggest removing the `var` in that line